# Contact Detail syncing between people app and my app

Tags: android, contacts, syck

I am involved in a project which has the functionality like whatsapp does for contacts.My app have to get the contact from phone(ie Peoples app) and sync it to server to find the users who are all already involved in my app.If a user not involved already i need to place a invite button.

For sync there is no problem i implemented a sync adapter,I have to get the updates like new phone no added or name changed in the contacts of people app.

I think `VERSION` and `CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP` fields are not exactly what i need.Because they may be updated when other details in the 
are changed.

I need to monitor the contacts change when my app starts,if there any changes in contacts i need to get that contact details and send it to server to know his status.Is running a `service with content observer`
will work for this case.
If it works how can i get the updated contact details.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Workaround is add a observer and get whenever any changes occur in contact. ISSUE: this will says a change has been done but don't give you what is the change or which contact has been changed. So their should be some logic or iterate all and do needful. But I AM REALLY SURPRISE WITH WHATAPP UPDATES.